# Rails - Multi way object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Problem:

I'm using active admin to allow the creation of an object, let us call it, @event. Event
has lots of fields, though not a problem because we're on the backoffice. However users of the front end can also create @event's, and it's a requirement of the application, that the @event object is created in a wizard form step by step.

My question is, using wicked, how can i separate the field validation logic between the one needed for the wizard AND the one needed on the backend. The main difference is that the wizard needs to validate certain fields based on the current wizard step, while in the backoffice all validations apply upon create/save. I'm following https://github.com/schneems/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step
and http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=asciicast.

Should I use a different model with same table, one for the backend and one for the front-end? Which is the best pattern or solution to follow in this type of problem where an object can be build all at once or step by step?

Thanks!

### **Edit**

Active admin controller is in charge of the object creation on the backoffice, EventsController and EventStepsController are the ones in charge of the front.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a different model but a different controller for the same model.

You could have a 'backend/event_controller.rb' and a 'frontend/event_controller' that act on the same object but on different ways ...

Hope this helps
Cheers

Comment: I already have different controllers because active admin includes its own one and i have another to handle the wizard. The root of the question is how to handle the validation logic of the MODEL, because i need to partially validate fields as the user moves through the form on on side, and validate all fields at once when admin creates a new instance through the backoffice. You see the problem now?

Comment: Ok I see... Maybe you could perform only "client side" validation on each step of the wizard and store their values in a temporary variable, and at the end of the wizard perform the entire server side validation on all the values you have stored at each step of the wizare using this time the validation logic of the model...